# GraphQL filter products by tags AND priceRange

Tags: graphql, shopify-api

I'm using the [shopify-buy](https://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/#documentation) SDK and the fetchQuery function to issue the following payload:

```
first: 50
query: "tags:[new] AND priceRange:{minVariantPrice:0 AND maxVariantPrice:40}"
reverse: false
sortKey: "PRICE"
```

This is returning all products, and as far as I can tell the tags filter isn't working either. Where am I going wrong here? Here is the issued command:

```
fragment ProductFragment on Product {
  id
  availableForSale
  createdAt
  updatedAt
  descriptionHtml
  description
  handle
  productType
  title
  vendor
  publishedAt
  onlineStoreUrl
  options {
    id
    name
    values
  }
  images(first: 250) {
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
    }
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        id
        src
        altText
      }
    }
  }
  variants(first: 250) {
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
    }
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        ...VariantFragment
      }
    }
  }
}

fragment VariantFragment on ProductVariant {
  id
  title
  price
  priceV2 {
    amount
    currencyCode
  }
  presentmentPrices(first: 20) {
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
    }
    edges {
      node {
        price {
          amount
          currencyCode
        }
        compareAtPrice {
          amount
          currencyCode
        }
      }
    }
  }
  weight
  available: availableForSale
  sku
  compareAtPrice
  compareAtPriceV2 {
    amount
    currencyCode
  }
  image {
    id
    src: originalSrc
    altText
  }
  selectedOptions {
    name
    value
  }
  unitPrice {
    amount
    currencyCode
  }
  unitPriceMeasurement {
    measuredType
    quantityUnit
    quantityValue
    referenceUnit
    referenceValue
  }
}

query ($first: Int!, $query: String, $sortKey: ProductSortKeys, $reverse: Boolean) {
  products(first: $first, query: $query, sortKey: $sortKey, reverse: $reverse, after: "eyJsYXN0X2lkIjoxNTQzODk0MjM3MjM5LCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiMTU0Mzg5NDIzNzIzOSJ9") {
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
    }
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        ...ProductFragment
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: docs/specs for this 'query' param?

Comment: @xadm, I'm not sure what you're asking?

Comment: I found  .... https://shopify.dev/concepts/about-apis/search-syntax

Comment: `tag`, not `tags` - the rest not supported ... https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/queryroot#products-2020-04

Comment: Oh, man. `tag` was the solution for items incorrectly showing. You're saying I can't use `priceRange` though?